# Evaluate $\int{\frac{e^{-\sin x}\sin 2x}{\left( \sin x-\cos x \right) ^4}\text{d}x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral
$$
\int{\frac{e^{-\sin x}\sin 2x}{\left( \sin x-\cos x \right) ^4}\text{d}x}
$$

I tried a lot of ways but none of them worked. Also I tried to use *Mathematica* to solve it, but there's no result either. So **my question is**, does this integral have elementary closed forms? If not, how to prove it? (We may use [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)))

Comment: Why have you tagged this with abstract-algebra?

Comment: Since this may relate to [Differential Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra)

Comment: Is this problem from an ongoing contest? See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947928/find-int-frace-sin-x-sin-2x-sin-x-cos-x4dx?noredirect=1&lq=1) here.

Comment: Not an ongoing contest, but is from a Chinese Q&A website