# Find $\int \frac{e^{-\sin x}\sin 2x}{(\sin x-\cos x)^4}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This problem comes from [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/434694566), I wonder whether it has an elementary closed form or not.

Maybe, we can make a transformation first as follows
\begin{align*} \int \frac{e^{-\sin x}\sin 2x}{(\sin x-\cos x)^4}{\rm d}x=\int \frac{e^{-\sin x}\sin 2x}{(\sin 2x-1)^2}{\rm d}x=\int \frac{e^{-\sin x}}{\sin 2x-1}{\rm d}x+\int \frac{e^{-\sin x}}{(\sin 2x-1)^2}{\rm d}x, \end{align*}
but this seems helpless, and WA gives no results.

Comment: Your link gives a 404 error.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Probably, the questioner deleted it himself.

Comment: Maybe useful \begin{align*} 
\int \frac{\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos^4(x)}}{\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)^4}{\cos^4(x)}}{\rm d}x=
\int \frac{2\tan(x)(1+\tan^2(x))}{(1-\tan(x))^4}=\int \frac{2u\,du}{(1-u)^4}
 \end{align*}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947749/evaluate-int-frace-sin-x-sin-2x-left-sin-x-cos-x-right-4-textd   Are we sure this is not an ongoing contest?